# Need help connecting to Dentrix G4 through ODBC

Tags: odbc, dentrix

I'm looking for a way to connect to a Dentrix G4 db to extract certain data.  We've had hit-and-miss luck.  Does anyone know of an ODBC to connect to Dentrix G4?

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen anyone successfully get in through ODBC. G4 database files can be accessed directly. Open the Patient.dat file in the dentrix data folder as binary or in a hex reader and us hex/Decimal/string conversion to get the unknown data back to Human readable text. Not a great solution but it should be possible to get the data out of the system.

Comment: Is there any way to connect to the database using Node.js I found a way to connect using C#.